# Unable to run flutter in windows X64 -Nuget.exe not found

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Any time I try to run flutter in windows, I get the errors below

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\Users\pannam\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\lock' for operations on 'C:\Users\pannam\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\Users\pannam\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\lock' will allow NuGet to continue.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/geolocator_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:33 (message):
  Failed to install nuget package Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.210806.1


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you already tried to remove the file `C:\Users\pannam\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\lock` as suggested in the error stack trace but if you have not you can try to do so.

Otherwise, you can run 'flutter clean' on your app root folder.

If it still don't work, you can try remove the windows folder and run the command `flutter create --platforms=windows .` It will recreate the windows folder properly.

For your information, you CAN potentially run a Windows application with the first line in your terminal (I have this line everytime I launch my app on Windows).

`Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.`

The real interesting part of the error are the next lines.